# Difference between Handler_write and Innodb_data_writes

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.5

[Handler write](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Handler_write) is the number of requests to insert a row in a table.
[InnoDB data writes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Innodb_data_writes) is the total number of data writes.

### Questions are

1. Does inserting a row count as a disk write?
2. If I do an insert operation in MYISaM engine which will get incremented?
3. If I do an insert operation in InnoDB engine which will get incremented?
4. If Handler_write is the number request to insert a row then why does it gets incremented every-time I run select queries.

   ```
   mysql> select VARIABLE_VALUE as value from information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS WHERE VARIABLE_NAME="Handler_write";
   +--------+
   | value  |
   +--------+
   | 195556 |
   +--------+
   1 row in set (0.00 sec)

   mysql> select VARIABLE_VALUE as value from information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS WHERE VARIABLE_NAME="Handler_write";
   +--------+
   | value  |
   +--------+
   | 195557 |
   +--------+
   1 row in set (0.00 sec)

   mysql> select VARIABLE_VALUE as value from information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS WHERE VARIABLE_NAME="Handler_write";
   +--------+
   | value  |
   +--------+
   | 195558 |
   +--------+
   1 row in set (0.00 sec)
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the answers based on the storage engine in use

> Does inserting a row count as a disk write?

For MyISAM, I would say yes because a MyISAM table keeps its total row count in its header. Inserting a row into a MyISAM would consequently impose an additional write to the table header to update the row count.

For InnoDB, the disk writing activity to a table is delayed until row changes have to traveled throughout the InnoDB Plumbing as shown in this Pictorial Representation from Vadim Tkachenko (Percona CTO)

[image: dskxn]

A newly inserted row would go into the InnoDB Buffer Pool, double write buffer (inside ibdata1), and the redo log (ib_logfile0,ib_logfile1).

For a table using the MEMORY storage engine, it would have to be no because the table's data and indexes reside in memory.

> If I do an insert operation in MyISAM engine which will get incremented?

Yes

> If I do an insert operation in InnoDB engine which will get incremented?

Yes

> If Handler_write is the number request to insert a row then why does it gets incremented every-time I run select queries.

Look at the design of `information_schema.global_status`

```
mysql> show create table information_schema.global_status\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: GLOBAL_STATUS
Create Table: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `GLOBAL_STATUS` (
  `VARIABLE_NAME` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `VARIABLE_VALUE` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Every time, run a SELECT against this table, mysqld has to update the table by writing new row information. This is by not adding a new but updating `VARIABLE_VALUE` for `VARIABLE_NAME` = 'Handler_write'. An `UPDATE` is just a viable a write source as an `INSERT`. Keep in mind that [Handler_write](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Handler_write) is storage engine agnostic. In that case, it's just a metric for write requests without knowledge of the storage engine layer.

Answer (score 1):

A "write" is distinct from a "disk write".

Writes include writes to tmp tables.

This pattern avoids having to do subtracts (for Handler%, not for Innodb%):

```
FLUSH STATUS;
perform some query;
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
```

`Innodb_%` values are only `GLOBAL`; `Handler%` are `SESSION`, then added to the `GLOBAL` tallies.

`Handler%` is done at an engine-agnostic level; `Innodb%` is done in the InnoDB engine.  (This should answer you engine questions, but I have not double checked.)

Fraction of read requests that had to hit disk =
  `Innodb_buffer_pool_reads / Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests`
Possibly the numerator needs to be `Innodb_pages_read` or `Innodb_data_reads`.

Sorry that I don't have answers to all your questions.